# Python SQL connections

Tags: python

How to dump/load data from python test response to a database table(SQL)?

Assuming I know nothing, can you guide me or provide all the possible ways to dump/load/store data from a pytest response to a SQL table

Comment: You need to provide more information for someone to contribute a relevant answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for a guide on asking a good question

Comment: Specifically, it would be great to understand which type of SQL database you want to use as well as what a pytest response is (is it the entire output of your pytest report?)

Answer (score 0):

Below are the high level steps you should take to load data into a SQL database. The lack of context makes it impractical to go into further detail.

1. Set up a database (choose one, install it, configure it).
2. (Usually) change the database schema to suit your needs. (Could also happen after #3.)
3. Connect to the database from wherever you have the data.
4. Insert the data into the database.

Maybe [this example](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html) will help.

I don't know what you mean by "responses".